# How to set default programs for all users on a Windows Terminal Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I want to set a standard email-program (including .eml files, MAILTO and Mapi) for all users on a Windows Terminal Server 2008. I was told, that "Group Policy Properties" could do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the program.  For a generic procedure to integrate programs into Terminal server, you can look here.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186498

The unofficial method is to logon as the Server admin, go into Internet Options and set the Email client there.  This changes the registry setting at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail` and the changes are inherited by all users.